# Initializing cluster partition table arrangement... in Hazelcast 3.9.1 takes too long

Tags: java, performance, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am trying to create a **Hazelcast** service Project wherein I will be subscribing to a RDBMS (Oracle DB 12c) datastore, create a POJO/Java Bean on the fly using reflection and then parsing that Java Bean object to map the JDBC ResultSet as Result row values into the Java Bean object and load those mapped objects into the Distributed Map.

I checked the data volume of the two tables from which I'm trying  to load in the **Hazelcast IMap** and it is as low as 0.0625 and 0.0316 MB. So this is a simpler Hazelcast implementation just initializing two parallel instances/nodes on localhost.

I'm timing in the Java Main method the total run time from the instant the Java POJO class is created and each of the corresponding Object is created and loaded in the Hazelcast IMAP.

In my understanding, this is taking too long from a system perspective because we are seeing similar behavior even in test and prod boxes with system specs
3 to 4 times better than the one given below. Kindly help giving suggestions on whats wrong with or is this a usual for the first time partitioning within a 
hazelcast IMDG with 2 nodes in a cluster.

The system specifications are as follows:

Macbook Pro 2014
Processor: 2.6 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory: 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Please find the logs...

Feb 26, 2018 10:30:39 AM com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.PartitionStateManager
INFO: [xx.xxx.xx.xxx]:5702 [dev] [3.9.1] Initializing cluster partition table arrangement...
Number of entries in userMaster Map: 883

Number of entries in userMaster Map: 7499

Duration approx was:92520 milliseconds
Feb 26, 2018 10:32:10 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [xx.xxx.xx.xxx]:5701 [dev] [3.9.1] [xx.xxx.xx.xxx]:5701 is SHUTTING_DOWN

Comment: Are you reflecting on all 883s row in the result set ? What makes you think Hazelcast is slow -- can you put logging in the `MapLoader.load`, `loadAll` and `loadAllKeys` methods ?

Comment: I had created a Class based on reflection and created Objects to put directly in the map rather than using Maploader implementation for persistence. But regardless I was running my program for 2 tables one with 883 records and other with 7499 which is taking a tad too long based on specs. Can you please specify whether using MapLoader be more performant.

Comment: Hi, I tried creating MapLoader with different Server and client running on the same machine with `loadAllKeys()`  implemented with correct keySet(). Is this called when the server (Hazelcast Instances are created) through a separate jar or when the client is called. `<map name="userMaster">
        <map-store enabled="true" initial-mode="EAGER">
            <class-name>com.beans.JPojo</class-name>
        </map-store>
    </map>` The above was the config in hazelcast.xml of the server to run. But its not loading anything in the IMap either on server start or through client invoke.

Comment: Without a `MapLoader` your processing reads as if it is serial. One process loads from Oracle and saves to the grid nodes. With a `MapLoader` this is parallelised, each grid node directly reads the share of the data it is hosting. Potentially on a 2 node grid the load time will half, but there are other factors that will influence this, such as how does the database cope with twice the connection load.

Comment: Are you able to create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and share it somehow ? That might help in understanding what's going wrong. Github would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Although I wasn't able to fix the MapLoader issue the main issue with the ResultSet `setFetchSize()`. This was set as 10 which was causing the network i/o to be too high. Once I increased to say 1000 or more it is coming out to be much quicker.

LOGS:

With Regular FetchSize():
preparedStatement.getFetchSize():10
Feb 28, 2018 7:24:51 PM com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.PartitionStateManager
INFO: [xx.xxx.xx.xx]:5702 [dev] [3.9.1] Initializing cluster partition table arrangement...

Number of entries in userMaster Map: 26464

Duration approx was:276178 milliseconds

With Bigger FetchSize():

preparedStatement.getFetchSize():1000
Feb 28, 2018 7:31:06 PM com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.PartitionStateManager
INFO: [xx.xxx.xx.xx]]:5702 [dev] [3.9.1] Initializing cluster partition table arrangement...responseCode:404 url:http://localhost:8080/mancenter/collector.do
Number of entries in userMaster Map: 26464

Duration approx was:11279 milliseconds

I would certainly be posting the server and the client version of the code for help with MapLoader which sounds like the best approach.

As a further help, can you provide some info as to whether the  `extends Mapload/Mapstore technique` can be written for objects/classes which are created Runtime since the smaller example I tried separately was with a fixed Java Bean.

I remember the documentation mentioning the `MapStoreFactory()` option. Will this be helpful.

Comment: This might get you started with [MapStore](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-map/mapstore). A `MapStoreFactory` is more useful if you want to plug in a `MapStore` that is a Spring Bean or has some other complex configuration